# Rails curl syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I can run the following command from my rails app:

```
Hash.from_xml(%x{curl -d "admin=true" http://localhost:8888} ) rescue nil
```

now I want to replace the "admin=true" by a variable
If I have x = "admin=true"
how can I then write the above command?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please, please be careful using code like this.  If you every make a query on behalf of user and pass untrusted input on to curl, this could lead to a shell injection attack.  That said, using a fixed string should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use curl directly in Ruby instead depending on command and hardcoded parameters - current code is harder to maintain and doesn't tell you exactly what may be wrong if something bad happens. See [ruby curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ruby/).

The ideal option actually would be dropping use curl and use [rest-client](http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client).

```
Hash.from_xml(RestClient.get('http://localhost:8888/', :admin=>true))
```

No dependencies - just pure ruby. Proper exceptions raised in any case. Trivial parameter specing. POST verb available.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = %Q{"admin=true"}
Hash.from_xml(%x{curl -d "#{x}" http://localhost:8888} ) rescue nil
```

The `%Q{}`syntax indicates a quoted string, which is kind of like a "super"/"enhanced" version of a double-quoted string.

The `#{}` syntax inside `%x{}` is called *interpolation* and it allows to evaluate Ruby code inside a string.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this: if 'admin=true' is generated dynamically, you need to be absolutely sure that this string does not contain anything that could be used for a shell injection attack [this is generally tough to do].  And, if it's not generated dynamically then there's no reason to use %Q.  gertas' solution is much more robust.