# Curl on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, curl, ruby-on-rails-3.1

how to use curl on ruby on rails? Like this one

```
curl -d 'params1[name]=name&params2[email]' 'http://mydomain.com/file.json'
```

Comment: do u have a special requirment to use cUrl, coz I think you could use ruby HTTP post method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810650/help-me-converting-this-curl-to-a-post-method-in-rails

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269224/ruby-https-post-with-headers

Comment: you should use `Net::HTTP`.

Comment: @shweta
Can you give me some example?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just in case you don't know, it requires 'net/http'

```rb
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse("http://example.org")

# Shortcut
#response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"user[name]" => "testusername", "user[email]" => "testemail@yahoo.com"})

# Full control
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data({"user[name]" => "testusername", "user[email]" => "testemail@yahoo.com"})

response = http.request(request)
render :json => response.body
```

Hope it'll helps others.. :)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a curl to ruby's net/http converter: https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/

For instance, a `curl -v www.google.com` command is equivalent in Ruby to:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

# response.code
# response.body
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic example of what you are trying to do is to execute this with backticks like this

```
`curl -d 'params1[name]=name&params2[email]' 'http://mydomain.com/file.json'`
```

However this returns a string, which you would have to parse if you wanted to know anything about the reply from the server.

Depending on your situation I would recommend using Faraday. https://github.com/lostisland/faraday

The examples on the site are straight forward. Install the gem, require it, and do something like this:

```
conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://mydomain.com') do |faraday|
  faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
  faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
  faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
end

conn.post '/file.json', { :params1 => {:name => 'name'}, :params2 => {:email => nil} }
```

The post body will automatically be turned into a url encoded form string.
But you can just post a string as well.

```
conn.post '/file.json', 'params1[name]=name&params2[email]'
```

Comment: uninitialized constant TestController::Faraday
I's successfully install the gem.. what is the problem?

Comment: Did you add the Gem to the Gemfile? and then run `bundle install`, usually those kidns of constant errors means it hasn't been loaded.

Comment: Yes I'm through with that.

Comment: Could you post a pastie (http://pastie.org/) of where you are putting the Faraday code?